# sendmail stops sending emails after sometime

Tags: centos-7, sendmail

I've a fresh install of CentOS 7 (followed this guide on howtoforge https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-7-apache2-mysql-php-pureftpd-postfix-dovecot-and-ispconfig3 )  and it has sendmail. Problem is after sometime sendmail stops delivering emails. After I do this it works and sends all mails in the queue. But then for some reason it stops sending emails again.

```
cd /etc/mail
make
make restart
```

these are the lines when it fails to send emails

```
Mar 17 15:53:18 ******** postfix/smtpd[9868]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 17 15:53:18 ******** sendmail[9948]: v2HCrIqC009948: from=********@gmail.com, size=245, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201703171253.v2HCrIqC009948@********.********>, relay=root@localhost
Mar 17 15:53:18 ******** postfix/smtpd[9868]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 17 15:53:18 ******** sendmail[9948]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=****************-SHA384, bits=256/256
Mar 17 15:53:18 ******** postfix/smtpd[9868]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: <********@gmail.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<********@gmail.com> to=<********@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<********.********>
Mar 17 15:53:18 ******** postfix/smtpd[9868]: warning: hash:/etc/mailman/virtual-mailman is unavailable. open database /etc/mailman/virtual-mailman.db: No such file or directory
Mar 17 15:53:18 ******** postfix/smtpd[9868]: warning: hash:/etc/mailman/virtual-mailman lookup error for "********@gmail.com"
Mar 17 15:53:18 ******** postfix/smtpd[9868]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.0 <********@gmail.com>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<********@gmail.com> to=<********@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<********.********>
Mar 17 15:53:18 ******** sendmail[9948]: v2HCrIqC009948: to=********@gmail.com, ctladdr=********@gmail.com (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30245, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.3.0, stat=Deferred: 451 4.3.0 <********@gmail.com>: Temporary lookup failure
Mar 17 15:53:18 ******** postfix/smtpd[9868]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

Comment: Add a link to the specific guide please - so we can assess what could go wrong. By the look of the log, it seems misconfigured from the start...

Comment: Ok added the link

Comment: It looks a lot like you forgot to run the `ISPConfig 3` part of tutorial - or haven't run it properly. It's the most important step of the guide as running that php script basically configures your entire server. Try again with that step? If it won't help, we will need to see main config file of `amavis` and `mailman`, `/etc/postfix/master.cf`, `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Comment: Further more running make from inside `/etc/mail` to start services? That's just suspicious - where in the guide have you found this? Why aren't you using system service commands `systemctl start ...`